# Ошибка: error: use of undeclared identifier 'с'

Tags: c

Выводит ошибку **error: use of undeclared identifier 'с'**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string c, p;
        int k, n;
        k = atoi(argv[1]);
        p = get_string("enter text: ");
        n = strlen(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            с[i] = p[i] + k;
            printf("%c", c[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("you must pass two arguments.");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у вас в `с[i] = p[i] + k;` русская `с`.

Во-вторых, в СS50 `string` - это просто `char *`. Поэтому ваше `c[i]` - это попытка доступа через неинициализированный указатель.

Comment: хм, си я начал изучать недавно, указатели и работу с памятью еще не прошел, в питоне нет такого просто). можно как-нибудь упростить вариант "во-вторых"? а то я не понял, уж простите глупца)

Comment: @Lython: Ну мне по вашему коду не понятно, зачем вам вообще понадобился массив `c`. Зачем, правда? Почему не сделать внутри  цикла просто `char c = p[i] + k; printf("%c", c);`? Зачем массив? Не зная ответ на этот вопрос, я не могу судить о том, что и как тут исправлять.

Comment: ну, я хотел сохранить зашифрованный текст

Comment: @Lython: Ну тогда - только выделять память вручную. Когда вы уже знаете значение `n`, делать `c = malloc(n + 1)`. И не забывать добавлять нулевой терминатор в конце `c`, если вы хотите получить C-строку.

Comment: всё, перестаньте бить мой мозг